# are explanatory variables in multiple linear regression slopes?

Tags: statistics

In simple linear regression the formula is: $y = m \cdot x + b$.
 When there are multiple independent variables: $y = b_0 + b_1 \cdot x_1 + b_2 \cdot x_2 + \ldots $

I know that $x_1,x_2,\ldots $ represents different independent variables but what exactly is $b_1,b_2,\ldots$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the coefficients.

Suppose you keep the other variable fixed besides $x_1$. How much does increasing a single unit of $x_1$ would affect $y$? According to the formula, it would change by $b_1$. Similarly for the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the coefficients $b_i$ represent the slope in the direction $x_i$. The slope of the hyperplane, however is a slightly different story, as that has an orientation as well. It would be the vector-sum of all these individual vectors, *i.e.* $\mathbf{b}=(b_1, b_2,...,b_n)$.